# How to get title class of tag element regex

Tags: regex, vb.net

I'm trying to make a regex that grab the title of internet tag element. In particular in this [link](http://it.soccerway.com/a/block_competition_tables?block_id=page_competition_1_block_competition_tables_8_1_1&callback_params=%7B%22season_id%22:9757,%22round_id%22:27139,%22outgroup%22:false%7D&action=changeTable&params=%7B%22type%22:%22competition_league_table%22%7D)

how you can see there's the table "Classifica" with some teams, I would grab "Ultime 5 partite" form, if the user overlapping the mouse on the colorful box appear a team result for the specific day. I would grab this title class; so I realized a regex like this:

I make a regex like this: `.giornata_1_casa = Val(Regex.Match(Content, "<a href=""(.*)"" class=""(.*)"" title=""(.*)"">[D|W|L]</a>").Groups(1).ToString)`

but return me 0, I want grab for example the content: **Juventus - Chievo Verona 2 - 0**, in particular of each element tag.

This regex working good in the website page but in the link that I've posted here previously not working. Where's the mistake?

Comment: The link you give contains [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) with HTML in it. As such, `"` are escaped to be able to put them into the JSON. So the first thing to do is read the JSON with [some](http://www.ediy.co.nz/vbjson-json-parser-library-in-vb6-xidc55680.html) [parser](http://www.pozzware.com/pozzware/Corsi/Programmazione/VB.NET/JSON%20Library.aspx) for vb.net. Then I would advise you to treat the HTML like HTML and not use regexes, explained [here](http://htmlparsing.com/regexes.html). [This](http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack) is a vb.net html parser I could find.

Answer (score 0):

Regex is an unsuitable solution to the task at hand, because you're dealing with HTML parsing, and HTML cannot be defined with regular expressions. For example, what will happen if you enrcounter an element where `title` comes before `class`? What if some element has extra spaces in `title    =` or has `title='bla'` instead of `title="bla"`?

There's a million changes that will break your code while still satistying the HTML spec. You're introducing an unnecessary dependency on the exact order and syntax of HTML attributes in the `<a>` tag.

Just use an HTML or XML parser instead.

Comment: I know this, but now I would just adjust the regex. I know perfectly well that xml would be ideal.

Comment: @AntonEgo What's your actual input?

Comment: My input current is the content that you can see from the link I gave you.
I have already created an algorithm that acts as a parser and get that content, I just have to run the regex and I ask your help.